# How to solve accesiBee csp error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

In my magento 2 store we are facing an issue with accessiBe where accessiBe contents are not loading, when i check the console seeing the below error.
[image]

when we reach accessiBe team they have given meta tag like below and told to add in the header tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.acsbapp.com *.acsbap.com acsbap.com acsbapp.com;connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.acsbapp.com *.acsbap.com acsbap.com acsbapp.com *.wikipedia.org;media-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: *.acsbapp.com *.acsbap.com acsbap.com acsbapp.com;style-src 'unsafe-inline'"/>
```

But when i add this tag in the header its working but its restricting other third party csp's.

to resolve this i want add above permission in the csp_whitelist.xml fil.

But how can i convert above meta tag data in the csp_whitelist.xml format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="connect-src">
          <values>
              <value id="acsbapp_connect" type="host">acsbapp.com</value>
              <value id="acsbap_connect" type="host">acsbap.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_acsbapp_connect" type="host">*.acsbapp.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_acsbap_connect" type="host">*.acsbap.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_wikipedia" type="host">*.wikipedia.org</value>
          </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="script-src">
          <values>
              <value id="acsbapp_script" type="host">acsbapp.com</value>
              <value id="acsbap_script" type="host">acsbap.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_acsbapp_script" type="host">*.acsbapp.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_acsbap_script" type="host">*.acsbap.com</value>
          </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="img-src">
          <values>
              <value id="acsbapp_img" type="host">acsbapp.com</value>
              <value id="acsbap_img" type="host">acsbap.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_acsbapp_img" type="host">*.acsbapp.com</value>
              <value id="wildcard_acsbap_img" type="host">*.acsbap.com</value>
          </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

The ids of the value-elements are just names to keep track of them in your code.