# How to convert csp meta tag into csp_whitelist.xml format in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

below is the meat tag i want covert as per magento 2

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-
inline';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.acsbapp.com *.acsbap.com acsbap.com 
acsbapp.com;connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.acsbapp.com *.acsbap.com acsbap.com 
acsbapp.com *.wikipedia.org;media-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;img-src 'self' 'unsafe
-inline' data: *.acsbapp.com *.acsbap.com acsbap.com acsbapp.com;style-src 'unsafe-inline'"/>
```

how  can i convert above tag to csp_whitelist.xml format in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module and add these files:

1. `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml` (Its to turn off the report only mode, which is enabled by default)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </storefront>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

2. `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/csp_whitelist.xml` (adding the policies)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="acsbap" type="host">acsbap.com</value>
                <value id="acsbap-wildcard" type="host">*.acsbap.com</value>
                <value id="acsbapp" type="host">acsbapp.com</value>
                <value id="acsbapp-wildcard" type="host">*.acsbapp.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="acsbap" type="host">acsbap.com</value>
                <value id="acsbap-wildcard" type="host">*.acsbap.com</value>
                <value id="acsbapp" type="host">acsbapp.com</value>
                <value id="acsbapp-wildcard" type="host">*.acsbapp.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="acsbap" type="host">acsbap.com</value>
                <value id="acsbap-wildcard" type="host">*.acsbap.com</value>
                <value id="acsbapp" type="host">acsbapp.com</value>
                <value id="acsbapp-wildcard" type="host">*.acsbapp.com</value>
                <value id="wikipedia-wildcard" type="host">*.wikipedia.org</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

The following policies you had in questions have default values, hence I have not added those to the `csp_whitelist.xml` file.

1. default-src
2. media-src
3. style-src

You can read about this feature on the official documentation from Adobe:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/

Comment: great minds think alike ;-)
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368455/how-to-solve-accesibee-csp-error-in-magento-2/#answer-368474

Comment: HI @Ahmad, i have tried above method but still its not loading the accessiBe content, but when put that meta tag in the header its working. What we are missing?

Comment: did you just edit the file or did you "upgrade", cleaned cache etc.?

Comment: Is your module enable? Also as @Mario mentioned, have you cleared the cache? I have just tested and it works perfectly fine with the above code.